# Proof: Series converges $\implies $ the limit of the sequence is zero

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've been using the sentence:

> If a series converges then the limit of the sequence is zero

as a criterion to prove that a series diverges (when $\lim \neq 0$) and I can understand the rationale behind it, but I can't find a **formal proof**.

Can you help me?

Comment: How formal do you want the proof? As in a formal proof system such as Mizar or Coq?

Comment: Just a plain proof will do :)

Comment: I find it a little strange that you had trouble finding a formal proof.  For instance, every calculus textbook I have ever seen has a proof, as do many elementary analysis textbooks.  Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_term_test.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left ( \sum_{k = 1}^{n + 1} a_k - \sum_{k = 1}^{n} a_k \right ) = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n + 1} $$
And both sums will converge to the same number so the limit is zero. This is by far the easiest proof I know.

This is the Cauchy criterion in disguise by the way, so you could use that too.

Comment: You might want to correct your indices in the summations.

Comment: What is wrong with the indices?

Comment: Lona: Robin fixed them, see the edit history to see what was there.

Comment: This looks like the most clear answer to me, thanks people!

Comment: Also, "limit n->infty" needs to be added to the RHS of the equation.

Answer (score 3):

If we know that the sequence converges and merely wish to show it converges to zero, then a proof by contradiction gives a little more intuition here (although the direct proofs are simple and beautiful). Assume $a_n\to a$ with $a>0$, then for all $n>N$ for some large enough $N$ we have $a_n > a/2$ (take $\varepsilon = a/2$ in the definition of the limit). Now the sum diverges: $\sum_{n>N}a_n > \sum_{n>N}a/2 = \infty$. A similar argument works when $a<0$.

Comment: You are mistakingly assuming that the sequence actually converges to something. The other proofs also show that the limit exist, AND it is 0.

Comment: Indeed, I thought that this was the question - given that the sequence converges, then the limit is zero and not something else. I'll add this to my answer.